# Can I combine a long chain of sed commands into something shorter?

Tags: linux, unix, sed, text-formatting

i successfully wrote a long line that works well for my usage.
it get a file, and format the text to be as i want.

is it possible to make it shorter ?

```
wget http://user:password@192.168.1.100/details.cgx \
  && sed "s/value/\n/g" details.cgx >> step1 \
  && sed "s/text/</g" step1 >> step2 \
  && sed "s/id/</g" step2 >> step3 \
  && tr -d '<>/' < step3 >> step4 \
  && sed "s/formFanLevel/FanLevel/g" step4 >> step5 \
  && sed '123,155d' step5 >> step6 \
  && sed '79,120d' step6 >> step7 \
  && sed '57,66d' step7 >> step8 \
  && sed '47,48d' step8 >> step9 \
  && sed '37,44d' step9 >> step10 \
  && sed '13,26d' step10 >> VMCDF.txt \
  && rm step* && rm details.cgx
```

Comment: At *least* give us the courtesy of readable formatting.

Comment: (By "readable formatting", I did not mean backticks -- I meant newlines and indentation).

Comment: So, first -- you realize you can give `sed` more than one command, right?

Comment: as in, `sed -e 'foo' -e 'bar'` will do both `foo` and `bar`.

Comment: And this is a perfect use case for pipes: `foo | bar`, instead of `foo >file && bar file`.

Comment: (Frankly -- why are you converting `text` and `id` to characters that you then delete? If your goal is to parse a format, it might make more sense to give us the original format and let us try to build a better parser from the beginning, rather than only to provide a bunch of very messy code and let us try to infer the input and intended output from same).

Comment: i'm sorry i wanted to copy, paste, and edit, but it send it when i wanted to add a new line pressing enter...

is it better to read ?  :

Comment: The line numbers to delete make the code fragile.  Otherwise, all the `sed` and even the `tr` command can be subsumed into a single invocation of `sed`, either with multiple `-e '…sed command…'` options or using `-f script.sed` where `script.sed` is a file containing the commands in the `sed` script.  Using all those temporary files is a nightmare.  Even if you decided to keep the `tr` command, you could group the `sed` commands before into a single `sed` command, and the commands after into another single `sed` command — and connect those by pipes.

Comment: Can you explain what your `tr` command does? I have the suspicion that it does something you may not expect.

Answer (score 2):

I *think* you want this:

```
wget -O- http://user:password@192.168.1.100/details.cgx | sed -E '
    s/value/\n/g
    s/text|id/</g
    s,<>/,,g
    s/form(FanLevel)/\1/g
' | sed '
    13,26d
    37,44d
    47,48d
    57,66d
    79,120d
    123,155d
' > VMCDF.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

A good start would be to learn how the [pipe command (|)](http://www.linfo.org/pipes.html) can be used to pass the output from one program as input to the next - this would remove the need to create, reference and clean up all the intermediate files (step1 .. step10) from your command line.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a shell script that can apply the same command chain to any file, then use the script instead of typing all these lines.

If, though unlikely, you always use the same file, just make an alias for it by  giving a name to the command chain, eg:

```
    alias wgetsed='wget http://user:password@192.168.1.100/details.cgx \
    && sed "s/value/\n/g" details.cgx >> step1 \
    && sed "s/text/</g" step1 >> step2 \
    ...
    && rm step* && rm details.cgx'
```

You then add the code above to  ~/.bash_rc to make it permanent for your user account.